# I want the output to be saved in as per the attached image

Tags: python, networking, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fzxb.png)    from netmiko import Netmiko
import re
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

```
def process_ip(args):
    rtr_ip, username, password = args
    try:
        net_connect = Netmiko(device_type='cisco_ios', host=rtr_ip, username=username, password=password)
        if net_connect:
            print(f"Connected to the MPLS Jump host: {rtr_ip}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect to MPLS Jump Host: {rtr_ip}. Please use the correct method.")

        output = net_connect.send_command('sh ip os ne')

        net_connect.disconnect()

        pattern = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+\d+\s+(\S+\/\s*-)\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\S+)'
        matches = re.findall(pattern, output)

        # Check if there are any neighbor entries
        if len(matches) > 0:
            # Create a DataFrame to store the extracted information
            data = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=["Neighbor ID", "State", "Dead Time", "Address", "Interface"])

            # Add the IP address column to the DataFrame
            data.insert(0, "IP Address", rtr_ip)

            return data

        else:
            print(f"No neighbor entries found for IP address: {rtr_ip}")
            print()

    except Exception as e:
        error_msg = f"Error executing command on IP {rtr_ip}: {str(e)}"
        print(error_msg)
        with open('error.txt', 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write(error_msg + "\n")

    return None


# Read IP addresses from the text file
with open("IP9500.txt", "r") as ip_file:
    ip_list = [line.strip() for line in ip_file]

# Get the username and password from the user
username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

# Create an empty list to store the results
all_data = []

# Process each IP address in parallel using ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(process_ip, [(ip, username, password) for ip in ip_list])

    # Collect the results as they complete
    for result in results:
        if result is not None:
            all_data.append(result)

# Combine all the dataframes into a single dataframe
combined_data = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
combined_data.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
print("Data saved to output.xlsx")
```

I want to save the output in an excel file as per the attached image I am just firing one command on the router and from the output I am capturing some details using regex and I want to save that output in Excel against the router IP

I want to save the output in an excel file as per the attached image I am just firing one command on the router and from the output I am capturing some details using regex and I want to save that output in Excel against the router IP